# ViewHelper for links from link wizard

Tags: typo3

I search a ViewHelper which helps to recognize, wether a link from the link wizard is a page link, a file link or an external link.

The reason for this is:
i must include different icons depending from the link type, e.G.

```
header_link => '33'
header_link => 't3://file?uid=44'
header_link => 'spiegel.de'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no viewhelper for this out of the box. You could write your own viewhelper which uses `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\LinkHandling\LinkService::resolve()` to determine the type.

However I'd suggest to do this via CSS instead:

```
a[href^='http'] { /* external */ }
a[href^='/'] { /* internal */ }
a[href$='.pdf'] { /* pdf */ }
/* etc. */
```